# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

**html file**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="danger">
    <ion-buttons>
      <button ion-button navPop icon-only>
        <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-back" md="md-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title text-wrap>志愿者评选</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <h1>{{volunteer.title}}</h1><br/>
</ion-content>
```

**ts file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-volunteer-vote-detail',
  templateUrl: 'volunteer-vote-detail.html',
})

export class VolunteerVoteDetailPage {
  volunteer:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.volunteer = navParams.get('volunteer');
  }

}
```

In other pages, I used `this.volunteer = navParams.get('volunteer');` for get data, but here cannot get data and showing error for me

**Error:**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'title' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of
>   undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (VM3975 VolunteerVoteDetailPage.ngfactory.js:64)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (VM3846 vendor.js:14729)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (VM3846 vendor.js:13865)
>       at callViewAction (VM3846 vendor.js:14210)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (VM3846 vendor.js:14142)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (VM3846 vendor.js:13866)
>       at callWithDebugContext (VM3846 vendor.js:15092)
>       at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (VM3846 vendor.js:14629)
>       at ViewRef_.detectChanges (VM3846 vendor.js:11652)
>       at Tab.NavControllerBase.*viewAttachToDOM (VM3846 vendor.js:49817)
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (VM3975 VolunteerVoteDetailPage.ngfactory.js:64)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (VM3846 vendor.js:14729)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (VM3846 vendor.js:13865)
>       at callViewAction (VM3846 vendor.js:14210)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (VM3846 vendor.js:14142)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (VM3846 vendor.js:13866)
>       at callWithDebugContext (VM3846 vendor.js:15092)
>       at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (VM3846 vendor.js:14629)
>       at ViewRef*.detectChanges (VM3846 vendor.js:11652)
>       at Tab.NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM (VM3846 vendor.js:49817)
>       at c (VM3844 polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.reject (VM3844 polyfills.js:3)
>       at Tab.NavControllerBase._fireError (VM3846 vendor.js:49580)
>       at Tab.NavControllerBase._failed (VM3846 vendor.js:49573)
>       at VM3846 vendor.js:49620
>       at t.invoke (VM3844 polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvoke (VM3846 vendor.js:4979)
>       at t.invoke (VM3844 polyfills.js:3)
>       at r.run (VM3844 polyfills.js:3)
>       at VM3844 polyfills.js:3

Edit:

[image]

UPDATE:

**ts file**

```
goToVolunteerVoteDetail(volunteerItem:any) {
    this.navCtrl.push(VolunteerVoteDetailPage,{
      volunteer:volunteerItem
    });
  }
```

**html file**

```
(click)="goToVolunteerVoteDetail(volunteer)"
```

Comment: are you getting anything when `console.log(this.volunteer)`..?

Comment: Can get my data @Edison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable **volunteer** seems to be undefined. This due to a mistake in the line :

```
this.volunteer = navParams.get('volunteer');
```

Apparently you are not sending a parameter called volunteer. Therefore navParams is empty.
My advise is to go wherever page you're pushing from (or routing) and use **navcontroller** like this:

```
this.navCtrl.push(VolunteerVoteDetailPage, {
      volunteer: "yourDATA"
    });
```

Comment: I tried to add this to my pushing page.. and I update code in my question .please check

Comment: error solved.. thanks..and I don't know why I have to restart "ionic serve -l" then can show my backend data in this detail page

Comment: This is a frequent issue when developing ionic app. You usually have to restart the server..

Answer (score 2):

*From the comments*:

> Are you getting anything when `console.log(this.volunteer)`..?
>
> Can get my data

Since you're getting the data when using the `console.log`, it seems to be related to the data not being ready when Angular tries to create the view. In order to avoid this error, you could use the *elvis operator*, like this:

```
<h1>{{volunteer?.title}}</h1><br/>
```

This would prevent Angular from trying to read the `title` property if `volunteer` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks..no error showing... but still cannot get my data..and console.log showing undefined now..I updated screenshot in my question

Comment: @YuyangHe Could you please add the code where you're sending that value to the current page?

Comment: Dear downvoter could you please explain the reason for your vote? That way we can all learn :)

Comment: Sry for later reply..I am trying now...yesterday have meeting..and downvote not me sir..please